# issue at handling multithreading in java (using ThreadLocal)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm experiencing some issue at working multithreading in java. I am a student, java beginner and just developing this for entertainment purposes (sorry for bad grammar, english is not my first lang).

I'm doing a tiny downloader for personal use that accepts a maximum of 5 simultaneous downloads. Each download is handled by a different *thread* (not the common threads, just swingworker, which I also use to avoid UI freezing.).

```
   public static String PATH;                   //File path
   public static String NAME;                   //File name

   //Download Method
   public void download() { 
      //download code...
   }
```

This method works fine (it downloads a file and then saves it into the hard drive as expected). But the issue comes when I want to do two (or more) downloads **simultaneously**. Consider I am downloading two files at the same time, **file A** and **file B**. When I start the download of **A**, strings `PATH` and `NAME` obtain its values according to file *A*, all OK. Then, I start downloading **B** and the previous stored values from **A** are replaced with the values that correspond to **B**. So when the download of **A** is complete, the file name is the same that **B** should have when download B is completed.
Resuming, I need different ìnstances of the same variable, that will contain different and indepentant values.

I started to research about the topic and led to `ThreadLocal` variables. This type of variable is supposed to change in each running thread, just what I need.
I tried to implement this to my code.

```
   public static String PATH;                   //File path
   public static String NAME;                   //File name

   public ThreadLocal<String> TL_PATH =  new ThreadLocal<String>();
   public ThreadLocal<String> TL_NAME =  new ThreadLocal<String>();

   public void download() { 
   //Try to set ThreadLocal to PATH and NAME variables.
       TL_NAME.set(NAME);
       TL_PATH.set(PATH);

   //download code... 

   }
```

Once I did this, everything was the same. What's wrong in my code? (No exceptions are thrown in any case, just what I explained before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are doing it wrong

You should implement `Runnable` and have it take the url and path to download to.

Use `ExecutorService` set to `5` threads in the pool.

To manage the individual instances of the class that implements `Runnable`.

### Here is an example:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Q24591731
{
    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE;

    static
    {
        EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Download d1;
        try { d1 = new Download(new URL("www.someurl.to.download.com"), new File("dest/file/name")); }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        // create as many downloads as you need how ever you want.
        EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(d1);
        // when all are submitted
        EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdown();
        try
        {
            EXECUTOR_SERVICE.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    public static class Download implements Runnable
    {
        private final URL url;
        private final File dest;

        public Download(@Nonnull final URL url, @Nonnull final File dest)
        {
            this.url = url;
            this.dest = dest;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // download the file and write it to disk
        }
    }
}
```

### Exercise for the reader:

[ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) is a more appropriate solution, but it is a little more involved and works best with `Callable` instead of `Runnable`. Especially for `batch processing` like this. But I have examples on other answers here and don't feel like repeating that solution again.

Comment: Quite tricky and complicated for me at the moment. I will see if I can read a little bit more about that. My code has many classes and I don't know in which of them I can implement this. However, thanks for the answer. Now I know where to start.